# why my sliding box is not working as per specific divisions

Tags: php

```
<TD><script type="text/java script"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sliding div").hide();
    $("#show_hide").show();

  $('#show_hide').click(function(){
  $("#sliding Div").slide Toggle();
   });

  }); 
 </script>
 while ($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
 {
 ?>  
<div class="services_box">
<!--<div class="services_box_title"><h3 align="center">Location: </h3></div>-->
<div class="services_box_mid_cont">
<div class="inner 3" style="padding;">
<div class="inner 3_left"><a h ref="#"><img src="upload_image/
<?php echo $row   1['image']; ?>"  height="100px" width="150px"/></a></div>
<div class="inner3_right">
<div class="heading">
<label id=titl><a href="view.php?Post_id=
<?php echo   $row1['Post_id'];?>"><?php echo $row1['title'];?></a></label></div>
 <div class="para"><div style="width:380px; height:80px; overflow:auto;"> 
 <a id="desc"   href="#">&nbsp;<label id=desc><?php echo $row1['description'];?>
 </label>  </a></div> </div>
 <div class="btn"><a href="#" id="show_hide">
 <img src="images/button-reply.png" width="76" height="27" /></a></div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="date_time"><h3>Posted On :<?php echo $row1['date_time'];?></h3></div>
  <?php echo $row1['city']; ?> 
  <div class="contact_no">
  <h3 align="right">Contact:<?php echo $row1['user_mobno'];?> </h3></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div> 
 <div class="sliding Div" id="sliding Div">
 <div class="clear"></div>
  <table width="69" style="border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;">
 <tr class="head_bg">
  <TD width="132">Name</TD>
  <TD width="100">Email Id</TD>
  <TD width="194">Mobile</TD>
     </tr>
  <tr><TD col span="7" style="border-bottom:#CCCCCC 1px solid;"></td></tr>
  <tr class="head_bg">
  <TD width="400"><input type=text></TD>
  <TD width="400"><input type=text></TD>
  <TD width="400"><input type=text></TD>
     </tr>
  </table></div>
```

this code is working for a single div only not for the all div. here is my div in while loop;i am trying my best to execute the code successfullyy but it is not working.
plz immidiate ly tell me the solution..

Comment: post your css code pls

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sliding Div").slide Toggle();
```

should be

```
   $("#sliding Div").slideToggle();
```

Comment: i have cheked but no effetct to the previous result

Answer (score 0):

You have give the id name as:

```
id="sliding Div"
```

Change it to `id="sliding_div"` in the id there should not be space.

OR you can use the below JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".sliding").hide();
 $("#show_hide").show();

  $('#show_hide').click(function(){
     $(".sliding").slideToggle();
  });

});
```